# Trim string with array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, trim

How can i trim with array of string in php. If I have an dynamic array as follows :

```
$arr = array(' ','<?php','?>',"'",'"');
```

so how can i use this array in `trim()` to remove those string, I tried very hard in the code below :

```
$text = trim(trim(trim(trim(trim($text),'<?php'),'?>'),'"'),"'");
```

but i can not use this because array is dynamic, it may have more than 1000 values.
It takes a lot of time to turn into a loop even after trying it.So I can do anything as follows

```
$text = trim($text, array(' ','<?php','?>',"'",'"') );
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve with this in the end? `trim` cannot be used to remove *strings* (more than one specific character at a time) from strings. I.e., `trim('faabar', 'bar')` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Should have clarified before I answered :-(

Comment: @deceze : trim can remove multi character but i want remove multi string.

Comment: So you want to remove `<?php` etc from the $text string?

Comment: @BhavikHirani `trim('faabar', 'bar')` results in `f`, not in `faa`!

Comment: Put another way, `trim($foo, '<?php')` and `trim($foo, 'p?h<')` do the same thing!

Comment: @deceze : yes you are right, but 'bar' consider as multi string like 'b','a' & 'r'. but how can i use '<?php', '?>' ," those string as array

Comment: Well, you can't, not with `trim`. So, again: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?! Why are you trying to remove PHP delimiters from strings?!

Comment: i have multiple php file, i want to marge those files. so first i have to remove '<?php' and '?>' before marge

Comment: Unless you have very specific limitations that your files all adhere to, merging random PHP files into one file can be quite a bit more complex than this. Why are you trying to merge PHP files?!

Comment: `$text = str_replace($arr, '', $text);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver: dear i can not use `str_replace` because file may content more '<?php' & '?>' string

Comment: @BhavikHirani are you turning every file into a string array?

Comment: @BhavikHirani If you're trying to package code up into a single executable, use PHAR.  Otherwise, don't merge PHP files.

Comment: Thanks to all, i got my ans ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to apply `trim()` function to an array.  The question seems to be unclear but you can use `array_map()`. Unclear because there are  other enough possible solutions to replace substrings. To just apply `trim()` function to an array, use the following code.

```
$array = array(); //Your array
$trimmed_array = array_map('trim', $array); //Your trimmed array is here
```

If you also want to fulfill the argument requirement in `trim()` you can apply a custom anonymous function to `array_map()` like this:

```
$array = array(); //Your array
$trimmed_array = array_map(function($item){
    return trim($item, 'characters to be stripped');
}, $array); //Your trimmed array is here
```

Comment: This is not my complete answer, but 50% of my work ended with this reply, thanks mate